# Generate Segments by halving recursively

Tags: c#, series

I need to recursively halve a number and make segments. until length of the segment is less than 1; ex. when the numbers is 15 we will have:

```
0,15 ==> 1 segment, length = 15 
0,7.5,15 ==> 2 segments, length = 7.5
0,3.75,7.5,11.25,15 ==> 4 segments, length = 3.75
0,1.875,3.75,5.625,7.5,9.375,11.25,13.125,15 ==> 8 segments, length = 1.875 
0,0.9375,1.875, ..... ,13.125,14.0625,15 ==> 16 segments, length = 0.9375
```

so far I can do this through a naive code as below:

```
double delta = N; //N being the input number
while(delta > 1.0)
    delta /= 2.0;
int count = (N / delta) + 1;
var series = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(x => x * delta).ToArray();
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError better algorithm.

Comment: "Better" is too vague. What sort of improvement are you looking for, performance versatility, style (opinion-based), ....?

Comment: I don't understand where the recursion is in your "recursive" solution; can you explain? This is an iterative solution, not a recursive solution.

Comment: Your solution seems like a perfectly good way to compute the logarithm; you could also use the `Math.Log2` method and round the result appropriately.

Comment: @EricLippert Or `Math.Log(N,2)` for those of us not yet on .Net Core :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method to compute the next highest power of 2 for 32-bit integers:

```
public int NextHighestPowerOf2(int n) {
    // if n > 2^31 then fails - answer can't fit in int
    if ((n & (n - 1)) == 0) // n is a power of 2
        return n << 1;
    else {
        --n;
        n |= n >> 1;
        n |= n >> 2;
        n |= n >> 4;
        n |= n >> 8;
        n |= n >> 16;
        return n + 1;
    }
}
```

You can compute `series` similarly:

```
var nhp2 = NextHighestPowerOf2(N);
var series = Enumerable.Range(0, nhp2+1).Select(n => (double)(n*N)/nhp2).ToArray();
```

**NOTE:** This is slightly different from your code in that it splits an initial power of 2 as well. Your code has segments of size 1 for an initial power of 2. If you want your code, just change the method to use only the `else` portion.

Comment: You should edit your original answer rather than posting a new one.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks - I was doing so, but apparently Stackoverlow got confused when I sat on the page in edit mode for a long time. It both timed out and posted the answer. I'll just delete the other answer.

Comment: @NetMage: That's happened to me a dozen times over the years and I never knew why!